# Converting date format?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// declares variables
string dayow;
string month;
string day;
string year;


int main()
{
cout << "Pick you day of the week (ex: Monday-Sunday)" << endl;
getline(cin, dayow);
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Pick your month (ex: January-December)" << endl;
getline(cin, month);
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Pick your day of the month (ex: 1-31)" << endl;
getline(cin, day);
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Pick your year" << endl;
getline(cin, year);
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "This is your date.." << endl;
cout << dayow << ", " << month << " " << day << ", " << year << "." << endl;
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Here are the 3 formats to display your date.." << endl;
cout << " " << endl;

 cout << "1. " << month << " " << day << " was a " << dayow << " in " << year    << endl;
cout << " " << endl;

std::string str = dayow;
std::string str1 = str.substr(0, 3);
std::string str = month;
std::string str2 = str.substr(0, 2);
std::string str = day;
std::string str3 = str.substr(0, 2);
std::string str = year;
std::string str4 = str.substr(0, 4);

std::cout << str1 << ", " << str2 << " " << str3 << " '" << str4 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

So what i'm trying to do here is get the user to input ex: Tuesday, March 22, 2012, then have 2 results come out. 1st being "January 1 was a Tuesday in 2012", that is fine as it is. Where the problem lies is the second result where I want "Tue, Mar 22, 2012" but the problem is on line 46 - 53, all of the strings are connecting to the first std:string str = dayow; so the output turns into TueTuTuTues!
Can anyone help?? thanks!

EDIT : Sorry if this is a noob questions :/ really new to coding!

Comment: This shouldn't compile. You have multiple definitions of `str`. How did you manage to get output from this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: (**some changes of your code**)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include<iostream> // **add this header file**
  #include <string>

  #include <fstream>

  using namespace std;

 // declares variables
string dayow;
string month;
string day;
string year;


int main()
{
cout << "Pick you day of the week (ex: Monday-Sunday)" << endl;
getline(cin, dayow);
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Pick your month (ex: January-December)" << endl;
getline(cin, month);
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Pick your day of the month (ex: 1-31)" << endl;
getline(cin, day);
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Pick your year" << endl;
getline(cin, year);
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "This is your date.." << endl;
cout << dayow << ", " << month << " " << day << ", " << year << "." << endl;
cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Here are the 3 formats to display your date.." << endl;
cout << " " << endl;

 cout << "1. " << month << " " << day << " was a " << dayow << " in " << year    << endl;
cout << " " << endl;

// **changes start here**
string str1 = dayow.substr(0, 3);

string str2 = month.substr(0, 3);

string str3 = day.substr(0, 2);

string str4 = year.substr(0, 4);

cout << str1 << ", " << str2 << " " << str3 << " ," << str4 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which compiler do you use? Your program shouldn't compile.

1. Add `#include <iostream>`
2. You cann't define few variables with same name C++.
   So replace

   ```
   std::string str = dayow;
   std::string str1 = str.substr(0, 3);
   std::string str = month;
   std::string str2 = str.substr(0, 2);
   std::string str = day;
   std::string str3 = str.substr(0, 2);
   std::string str = year;
   std::string str4 = str.substr(0, 4);
   ```

   with

   ```
   std::string str1 = dayow.substr(0, 3);
   std::string str2 = month.substr(0, 2);
   std::string str3 = day.substr(0, 2);
   std::string str4 = year.substr(0, 4);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

change this part:

```
std::string str = dayow;
std::string str1 = str.substr(0, 3);
std::string str = month;
std::string str2 = str.substr(0, 2);
std::string str = day;
std::string str3 = str.substr(0, 2);
std::string str = year;
std::string str4 = str.substr(0, 4);
```

to:

```
std::string str = dayow;
std::string str1 = str.substr(0, 3);
std::string stra = month;
std::string str2 = stra.substr(0, 3);
std::string strb = day;
std::string str3 = strb.substr(0, 2);
std::string strc = year;
std::string str4 = strc.substr(0, 4);
```

problem was you had same variable name for day,month and year

Comment: You're my hero! By any chance would you know how to change the date of Tuesday, March 22, 2012 into something like 2012-03-22 ? Just out of curiosity :p

Comment: well thats your homework, hint: use a loop for assigning months to numbers and format your output according to it :)